# Which model should I use? - Multi label classification

Tags: keras, dataset, data-science, multilabel-classification

I am newbie on data science so my question might be basic.

I have a dataset.  1st column is comments of people about issues (as text), 2nd columns is class/labels of that failure (as text). There are many failure types on my 2nd column.

I want to train a model. When another comment is entered and explained the issue, model should classify the failure.

Can I use Keras Sequential model? Or should I use different model? If you can share a link which can be related my question, I will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Keras Sequential model for sure. Now as a beginner, try using Dense layers, and you can also use Convolutional Neural Networks for it...
and btw try using the tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text Tokenizer to label each word as numbers so the machine can understand.

For more information, search on Google for text classification and search for the Tokenizer.